# Visual Studio Net Core Web App: No option to output as web app in project properties?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2017, publish

So I made a Net Core Web app project with razor pages and javascript files, as you can see on the right of the first screenshot, but I cannot seem to publish it as a web app, only console app or windows application.

For instance, when I publish it to folder, it does not even publish my razor pages, no index.cshtml at all.

Anyone ran into this issue before?

[Project properties screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Qax.png)

[Published folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay1tV.png)

[Inside wwwroot folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auqvp.png)

Comment: in .net core they get all compiled in.

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: meaning you won't see the razor pages as loose files. they are part of the dll

Comment: okay, but then how do I deploy it? From what I know, when you deploy any website, it has to look for a index.html page, which is the default page that is opened up when you launch the site.  
Which published file is the index page for razor pages?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: It says on there that 'An ASP.NET Core app is a console app that must be started when a server boots and restarted if it crashes.'  am I reading something entirely wrong? My ASP.NET Core app is a web app (its a chat website that works perfectly fine on my localhost)

Comment: I'm trying to deploy a web app made using net core, so I find it really weird that it says a net core is a console app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor pages `.cshtml` files will be embedded into the web.config file after publishing.

It seems like you are using a regular Linux FTP.  Make sure you are using a windows server to publish your app on.  Net Core does not work on Linux servers unless you install the Net Core runtime on the server.